# what the problem in this program? it doesn't use the second number, and doesn't print the last line?

Tags: c++, do-while

/*This program gets two positive numbers, declare "error" if the one of the numbers is negative, and then gets list
of numbers again and again until the amount of the list is bigger than the first number, or until the quantity of the
numbers in the list is equal to the second number, and ther prints the sum of the list.*/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num_list, tempSum, finalSum = 0, count = 0;
    cout << "enter 2 positive numbers:" << endl;
    cin >> num1;
    while (num1 < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        cin >> num1;
    }
    cin >> num2;
    while (num2 < 0)
    {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
        cin >> num2;
    }
    cout << "enter a list of numbers:" << endl;
    do
    {
        cin >> num_list;
        tempSum = num_list;
        finalSum += tempSum;
        count = count + 1;
    } while (count < num2 || finalSum <= num1);
    cout << finalSum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop keeps looping until **both** `count < num2` and `finalSum <= num1` become `false`. So, if only your `count < num2` condition becomes `false` (i.e.  `count >= num2`), the program will continue until both conditions become `false`.

You should use `} while (count < num2 && finalSum <= num1);` (if I understand correctly what you trying to achieve)

Comment: thank you Tanja, I wanted that the loop will be achieved if count< num2 or if 
finalSome < num2. what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||` in your `while` condition. 

The `||` doesn't mean that the loop will stop if either condition becomes `false`, it means that the loop will stop if **both** conditions become false.

Edit: if you want to understand it better, try using `} while (finalSum <= num1 || count < num2)` and see what happens - now your first number seems to be not taken into account. This is because the `while` loop waits for both of them to become `false`.

Comment: it's still doesn't work...

Comment: no I had a mistake, it's work! thank you!!